# Missing Component (Even though it exists)

Tags: cakephp, plugins, components, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to use this plug in https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-user-tools

When I try to access http://localhost/buildzero/test/register

It comes up with:

```
    Burzum/UserTools.UserToolComponent could not be found.

    Make sure your plugin was loaded from config\bootstrap.php and Composer is able to autoload its classes, see Loading a plugin and Plugins - autoloading plugin classes

    Error: Create the class UserToolComponent below in file: C:/wamp/www/buildzero/vendor/burzum/cakephp-user-tools/src\Controller\Component\UserToolComponent.php
```

Even though the file exists

```
    C:\wamp\www\buildzero\vendor\burzum\cakephp-user-tools\src\Controller\Component\UserToolComponent.php
```

I have followed the installation guide

`"burzum/cakephp-user-tools": "dev-develop"` was put under "require" in `composer.json` and all the dependencies were updated.

I have made the tables using

```
bin/cake Migrations.migrations migrate -p Burzum/UserTools
```

My TestController.php looks like

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class TestController extends AppController
{

    public $components = array(
    'Burzum/UserTools.UserTool'
    );

}
```

I have already added `Plugin::load('Burzum/UserTools');` in `config\bootstrap.php`

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I would give `php composer.phar dump-autoload` a try. It looks like that class is not auto-loaded by composer. Then next step would be to look into `vendor/cakephp-plugins.php` to see if the plugin references are added there.

Comment: Yes, try dumping autoload. Everything else looks right for me. I'm using the plugin in a few projects without issues and just tried to register in a test app I have, it works for me.

Comment: Thankyou! I can access the register, login screens etc now!
Now another problem arises (maybe it will warrant another thread).
When I try to register, the error `Could not send email: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()` comes up. Are there any guidelines on how to set this up for mine?

Comment: Or maybe is there a way to disable sending emails and requiring activation? And just log in with the registered user

Comment: Silly me, all I had to do was set `emailVerification` to false. 
How do I set this plugin to allow users with role 'admin' to edit and delete other users?